# How to pass parameters to EF stored procedure?

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I would like to call stored procedure from C# code. This is how I tried:

```
var result = db.ExecuteStoreCommand("TaskSchedule", new object[] { new ObjectParameter("treatmentDateFrom", dateTime)});
```

I am however getting the following error:

> No mapping exists from object type System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter to a known managed provider native
>   type.

Could you please advise me what am I doing wrong?

I've seen many posts about getting values out of SP, but I would like to pass my parameters into SP. I am using EF4.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing a stored procedure trough EF can be made real easy by mapping your SP to the ObjectContext.

In your EDMX designer you can import a stored procedure and map the result to a new type or to an existing type. After this the SP becomes a strongly typed function on your object context.

[Here is some documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896279.aspx) about importing SP's.

If you don't want to import your SP and use ExecuteStoreCommand, you need to make sure that you specifyc the parameters in your command text and that they are of type SqlParameter with the correct name and value.

Comment: I have added it to EDMX as import function. But there is no way to add any parameters to it. EDMX cant see that this procedure takes any parameters, altough SQL Management studio does.

I tried to edit EDMX manually and I added those parameters. I have also refreshed import function. Now I can call this procedure with appriopriate parameters:

var result = db.TaskSchedule(DateTime.Now, ...);

It compiles correctly, however Im getting the following error:
The data reader returned by the store data provider does not have enough columns for the query requested.